# Remove .php extension in .htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I have a test website on my ubuntu computer, the URL is: mysite.test.  I have marketing pages: http://mysite.test/hello.php, http://mysite.test/goodbye.php, etc.

I also have wildcard subdomains: http://user1.mysite.test/page1.php, http://user2.mysite.test/page.1php, etc.

I'd like all pages to be accessible without adding the ".php" extension (marketing site, and subdomains).  I've modified my .htaccess files, but its not working and I can't figure out why.  mod_rewrite is enabled and working (the "Remove www" rule below works).

```
#/var/www/mysite.test/public_html/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
#Remove www - this works
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC]

#Not need .php extension - this does not work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Removing the first rule ("Remove www") doesn't make it start working.

When I go to http://mysite.test/hello I get a 404 Not Found error.  Going to http://mysite.test/hello.php loads just fine.

When I go to http://user1.mysite.test/page1 I get a 404 Not Found error.  Going to http://user1.mysite.test/page1.php loads just fine.

My Virtual Hosts file looks like this:

```
#/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.test.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.test
    ServerAlias mysite.test
    ServerAdmin fake@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.test/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   <Directory /var/www/mysite.test>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wildcard.mysite.test
    ServerAlias *.mysite.test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.test/public_html/app

   <Directory /var/www/mysite.test/public_html/app>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing?  Thank you.

Comment: What happens if someone hits your site with `/foo/bar/baz`? You'll be rewriting to `foo/bar/baz.php`. Do those directories exist?

Comment: @marc-b I have added ``RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`` to the .htaccess file and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can give you a helpful solution to your issue, but I have a similar piece of code that works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.|/]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

this sets that if it is not a file, and if it doesn't contain a `.` (such as an image `reference.jpg` then it has `.php` appended to the filename.

This works perfectly for me.